# Consulta WHERE en elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Tengo esta consulta en elasticsearch:

```
$query= $es->search([
                  'index' => 'juguetes',
                  'from' => $f,
                  'size' => 50,
                  'body'=>[
                    'query'=>[
                          'query_string'=>[
                            'fields'=>['nombre','almacen','categoria'],
                            'query'=>'"'.$q.'"'

                          ], 
                    ],
                    'sort'=>[
                        'precio'=>['order'=>'asc'],
                    ]
                  ]           
                ]);
```

El query esta buscando en los campos nombre, almacén y categoría hasta ahí funciona bien, lo que necesito es que la búsqueda se pueda hacer sobre una categoría en especial, como una especia de where que me busque nombre y/o almacén donde categoría sea = a algo.

Estoy utilizando elasticsearch-php

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo resolviste? Solo tendrías que poner otra condición.

Comment: Hola @RodriKing gracias por responder, no lo he resuelto todavía.  Entonces tendri que repetir esto: 'query_string'=>[
                            'fields'=>['nombre','almacen','categoria'],
                            'query'=>'"'tienda'"'

                          ],

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres al menos un elemento de un set de elementos:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "terms": {
            "categoria" : [ ... caegoriesABuscar ... ] //Sean string o integers
        }
    }
}
```

Si solamente vas a querer un elemento en el "where":

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
            "categoria" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

Si lo que quieres es unir ambas queries necesitarás hacer uso de un Compound Query. En este caso utilizaría el siguiente payload

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "categoria": ["", "", ...]
                }
            },
            "should": {
                "query_string": {
                    "fields" : ["nombre", "almacen", "categoria"],
                    "query" : "Termino a buscar"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Te estoy indicando únicamente la parte del elemento query. El resto, sort, index, from y size mantenlos como los necesites.